# Text file parsing using java, suggestions needed on which one to use

Tags: java, text-parsing, readfile

I can successfully read text file using InputFileStream and Scanner classes. It's very easy but I need to do something more complex than that. A little background about my project first.. I have a device with sensors, and I'm using logger that will log every 10sec data from sensors to a text file. Every 10 sec its a new line of data. So what I want is when I read a file is to grab each separate sensor data into an array. For example:
velocity altitude latitude longitude

22 250 46.123245 122.539283

25 252 46.123422 122.534223

So I need to grab altitude data (250, 252) into an array alt[]; and so forth vel[], lat[], long[]...

Then the last line of the text file will different info, just a single line. It will have the date, distance travelled, timeElapsed..

So after doing a little research I came across InputStream, Reader, StreamTokenizer and Scanner class. My question is which one would you recommend for my case? Is it possible to do what I need to do in my case? and will it be able to check what the last line of the file is so it can grab the date, distance and etc.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Scanner. Take a look at the examples [here](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/scanning-text-with-java.util.scanner-3.html). Another option for you to use BufferedReader to read a line and then have parse method to parse that line into the tokens you want.

Also you might find this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717838/text-file-parsing-using-java-suggestions-needed-on-which-one-to-use/4717928#4717928) to be useful.

Very quick code base on the link above. The inputs array has your file data tokens.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in=null;
    List<Integer> velocityList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    List<Integer> altitudeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Double> latitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    List<Double> longitudeList = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    try {
        File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String string;
        String [] inputs;
        while ((string = in.readLine()) != null) {
            inputs = string.split("\\s");
            //here is where we copy the data from the file to the data stucture
            if(inputs!=null && inputs.length==4){
                velocityList.add(Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]));
                altitudeList.add(Integer.parseInt(inputs[1]));
                latitudeList.add(Double.parseDouble(inputs[2]));
                longitudeList.add(Double.parseDouble(inputs[3]));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            if(in!=null){
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //here are the arrays you want!!!
    Integer [] velocities = (Integer[]) velocityList.toArray();
    Integer [] altitiudes = (Integer[]) altitudeList.toArray();
    Double [] longitudes = (Double[]) longitudeList.toArray();
    Double [] latitudes = (Double[]) latitudeList.toArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks.. but how would I apply to what I need? In the last example from the link provided it looks for next data type (int, string).. what if i have string, int, int, int, float, float..

Comment: The Scanner class is very useful if you are dealing with different data types. In your case is the data always numeric?

Comment: data will be either int or float.. I didnt include all of my data but I will also have time and time elapsed both I want to be 'String'

Comment: Scanner has a method findInLine(String string), I can use that to grab my last line, if I will use a symbol to start that line like '%'. findInLine('%')? so it should grab the line after the symbol? what about the rest of the data to put it into arrays?

Comment: In order to convert them to Ineger or Double you can do Integer.parseInt(inputs[i]); or Double.parseDouble(inputs[i]);

Comment: the above code prints out the whole data from a file as a new line

Comment: Well it is just showing how to read the file a line at a time and then parse that line so that you can individual tokens on that line.

Comment: I'm able to grab every altitude in the file using this                                                                for(i = 1; i < inputs.length; i=i+4)                        System.out.println(inputs[i]);

Comment: I have provided a complete example for you with some comments. Hopefully this answers your question better.

Comment: Thank you this definetly answers my question! thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Reader + String.split()

```
String line;
String[] values;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
List<Integer> velocity = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> altitude = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Float> latitude = new ArrayList<Float>();
List<Float> longitude = new ArrayList<Float>();

while (null != (line = reader.readLine())) {
    values = line.split(" ");
    if (4 == values.length) {
        velocity.add(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        altitude.add(Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
        latitude.add(Float.parseFloat(values[2]));
        longitude.add(Float.parseFloat(values[3]));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

If you need arrays not list:

```
velocity.toArray();
```

As far I undestand data lines has 4 items and last line has 3 items (date, distance, elapsed time)

Comment: Actually arraylists are more applicable to what I need. Thank you I will try this out, looks like exactly what I need..

Answer (score 0):

As your data is relatively simple, `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer` should do the trick. You'll have to read ahead by one line to detect when there are no more lines left.

Your code could be something like this

```
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "your text file" ) );

      String line = null;
      String previousLine = null;

      while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
          if ( previousLine != null ) {
             //tokenize and store elements of previousLine
          }
          previousLine = line;
      }
      // last line read will be in previousLine at this point so you can process it separately
```

But how you process the line itself is really up to you, you can use `Scanner` if you're feeling more comfortable with it.

Comment: You can use String.split() instead of `StringTokenizer`, like `String[] fields = previousLine.split(" ")`

Comment: StringTokenizer.. will it convert every element to String? I need an array of int, and float..