# Create an Array populating it by .txt elements

Tags: java, arrays, file, file-io

I want to create an array, populating it while reading elements from a .txt file formatted like so:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

So the final result has to be an array like this:

```
String[] myArray = {item1, item2, item3}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717838/text-file-parsing-using-java-suggestions-needed-on-which-one-to-use/4717928#4717928 ... does this suffice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrap a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) around a `FileReader` so that you can easily read every line of the file;
2. Store the lines in a `List` (assuming you don't know how many lines you are going to read);
3. Convert the `List` to an array using `toArray`.

Simple implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    String[] array = lines.toArray();
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need!
:)

Answer (score 1):

This smells like homework. If it is you should re-read your notes, and tell us what you've tried.

Personally, I would use a Scanner (from java.util).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Franky {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
        String[] items = new String[3]; // use ArrayList if you don't know how many
        int i = 0;
        while(sc.hasNextLine() && i < items.length) {
            items[i] = sc.nextLine();
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sums up to a single line in Java 7 as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857273/3514386).

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

String[] myArray = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt")).toArray(new String[0]);
```