# Store each line in a text file into an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble attempting to store each line in a text file into an array. So far, my program is only able to read the file. Here is what i have so far.

```
public class assignment1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File fileName = new File("competitors.txt");
        try {
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out this other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12857731/6383857

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the `Scanner` until it has no more lines:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
try (Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(fileName)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        list.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: @D.Nik you should supply the correct full path